# OllyDbg - there are several patches applied but it still says that file was unmodified and doesn't save changes to modded *.exe

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ollydbg

OllyDbg - there are several patches applied but it still says that file was unmodified and doesn't save changes of patches to modded *.exe . Somehow before the addition of each new patch it saves ok with notice of changing the file, but with next it doesn't. And with the third I don't know how to overcome it. How to save them - am I doing something wrong?

```
The message
```

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to save the patches? What options are you using?

Comment: There are no options. Just right click on the code, save to file - then right click save to file once again. In patches window - all patches applied.

Comment: But when you right click in the CPU window the is no `Save to file` option

Comment: edit->Save to file

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your comments - There is no such `Save to file` or `Edit -> Save to file` when you right click in the `CPU` window. You are doing somethng wrong.

The correct way to save the patches to new file is:

1. Open `CPU` window
2. `Right click -> Copy to executable -> All modifications`

[image: Point two]

3. Click `Copy all` in the new window

[image: Point three]

4. In the new window `Right click -> Save file`

[image: Point four]

Comment: Could it be different version? Then I still have to know how to save all the changes. <img src="https://sun9-32.userapi.com/c857636/v857636178/1f7078/4oP_5500MfY.jpg">

Comment: It looks like it is not code (not executable section), so you aren't patching code. The section probably can be changed during program runtime, so thats probably the reason why you can't patch this